# EF Core: Filter query by complex property (which uses custom value converter)

Tags: .net-core, ef-core-3.1

guys.

I use EF Core 3.1 now as my database provider. So let's imagine a simple model of user with different working roles (for example, "worker", "builder", "supported", etc.)

```
public enum Roles
{
   Worker = 1,
   Builder = 2,
   Supporter = 3
}

public class User
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Roles> EmploymentRoles { get; set; }
    ...
}
```

with DbContext of

```
...
DbSet<User> Users { get; set; }
...
modelBuilder.Entity<User>().Property(f => f.EmploymentRoles).HasConversion(new JsonEnumCollectionToStringConverter<Roles>()); 

    public class JsonEnumCollectionToStringConverter<T> : ValueConverter<ICollection<T>, string> where T : Enum
    {
        public JsonEnumCollectionToStringConverter() :base(entity => JsonConvert.SerializeObject(entity), value => JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ICollection<T>>(value))
        {
        }
    }
```

So, It's not possible to write filter query directly like this:

```
var users = dbContext.Users.Where(e => e.EmploymentRoles.Contains(Roles.Worker)).ToList();
```

because EF Core can't translate Custom ValueConverter to SQL and execute this on the server-side. There are no warnings still now in 3.1.x, but this code will catch an error at the 5.x .NET.

So, what's the good way to write this filter query correct? I don't want to grab whole Users and filter it on the client-side, it can be worse in performance.

Thank you.